# Is there any way to configure my MVC with Spring without declaring every controller in a configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use thymeleaf to have an mvc.

I followed this tutorial and now works all fine `https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/` but I have issues when I want to map a /admin/somepage , for some reason is not being found (even if I added it on my `addViewController` method

At the example, they created a file `src/main/java/hello/MvcConfig.java` , is there any way I avoid this file and I have a configuration that allows me to dont have to add all controllers and views here and are automatically resolved from the controller file by the @RequestMapping ?

EDIT: here is the code

src/main/resources/templates/home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

src/main/resources/templates/hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the part I would like to get rid of...

src/main/java/hello/MvcConfig.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

At the controller I have the methods with the

```
@RequestMapping("/home")..
```

That returns a `ModelAndView`

Comment: Add the relevant code.

Comment: Is the same as the example of the link

Comment: For longevity you should still add the code here. Links can change and die and the post is meant to be useful to others in the future as well. Is it hard to copy paste it here?

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated the post with the code, could you check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a default handler to the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and the default handler to add is the [`UrlFilenameViewController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/UrlFilenameViewController.html).

If you followed the guide you are using Spring Boot. You would need to obtain the preconfigured `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and set the desired property. You can use a `BeanPostProcessor` for that.

```
public class YourBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
              ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean).setDefaultHandler(new UrlFilenameController());
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This way urls that aren't matched will be handed always to the `UrlFilenameController` to be resolved to a view name.

**Note:** It might be that you need to register it on a different `HandlerMapping` based on the number of available `HandlerMapping`s. As now always the the `UrlFilenameController` is returned and this might lead to other `HandlerMapping`s not being consulted anymore.